# App failure after apk signing

Tags: java, android, android-resources, jarsigner

My Android app works properly in development. But after signing it for production release, I got the errors below. I don't understand why this has happened.

```
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vasilkoff.walletgcn/com.vasilkoff.wallet.com.authorwjf.slot.SlotsList}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/reel_stop.wav from drawable resource ID #0x7f05000a
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/reel_stop.wav from drawable resource ID #0x7f05000a
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1722)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.media.SoundPool.load(SoundPool.java:191)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.vasilkoff.wallet.com.authorwjf.slot.SoundEffects.init(SoundEffects.java:31)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.vasilkoff.wallet.com.authorwjf.slot.SlotsList.onCreate(SlotsList.java:59)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     ... 11 more
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:428)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1719)
04-26 13:46:17.761: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     ... 17 more`enter code here
```

Bellow some logs of "jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs wallt-1.apk". Seems normal.

```
      X.509, CN=Vitali, OU=Grabovski, O=Vasilkoff, L=Inc, ST=Cherkasi, C=ua
      [certificate is valid from 25.10.13 14:57 to 28.07.68 14:57]

sm     20782 Fri Apr 25 16:02:58 EEST 2014 res/raw/reel_stop.wav

      X.509, CN=Vitali, OU=Grabovski, O=Vasilkoff, L=Inc, ST=Cherkasi, C=ua
      [certificate is valid from 25.10.13 14:57 to 28.07.68 14:57]

sm      5302 Thu Apr 17 01:28:16 EEST 2014 res/raw/send_coins_broadcast_1.wav

      X.509, CN=Vitali, OU=Grabovski, O=Vasilkoff, L=Inc, ST=Cherkasi, C=ua
      [certificate is valid from 25.10.13 14:57 to 28.07.68 14:57]
```

Comment: "res/raw/reel_stop.wav" seems to be missing

Comment: @HAR, it isn't missing. I've tried to discover "classes.dex" via dex2jar and jd-gui.